# Maven appassembler program properties

Tags: maven

I'm using the maven appassembler plugin to create an executable script that I can deploy to a server. I see that the plugin supports `commandLineArguments`, but how any thoughts on how I'd set -D properties?  Ideally, I'd be able to specify different -D values for each `<program>` entry.  e.g.

```
<programs>
    <program>
        <id>one</id>
        <mainClass>com.foo.One</mainClass>
        <propOne>one</propOne>
    </program>
    <program>
        <id>prime-image-cache</id>
        <mainClass>com.foo.Two</mainClass>
        <propOne>foo</propOne>
        <propTwo>bar</propTwo>
    </program>
</programs>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha! Not obvious, but seems to work.

```
<program>
    <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
    <id>app</id>
    <jvmSettings>
        <extraArguments>
            <extraArgument>-Dtest=false</extraArgument>
            <extraArgument>-Dlog4j.properties=false</extraArgument>
        </extraArguments>
    </jvmSettings>
</program>
```